# CakePHP: Models in AppController

Tags: cakephp

I've created a function in my appController to sendemails:

```
protected function sendEmail($studentId = null, $courseId = null, $action = null) {

    $course = $this->Course->find('first', array('conditions' => array('Course.id' => $courseId)));
    if(! $course) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid course'));
    }
}
```

I want to verify the course and student, but depending on which controller I call it from, I have to modify my $this->xxx->find statement. The only other solution I've came up with is validating/sending the $course/$student data head of time, but I'd still like to run a manual SQL query to save the email log (I'd run into the same problem). Any help?

Comment: If I understand correctly; just load the `Course` model in your `AppController`. Every controller will have access to it. That way, any controller will be able to call the function. `$this->loadModel('Course');` in the `sendEmail` function should do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand very good your problem, but:

If it's ok, or not, tel me.. come with an new ideea based on my code. I don't now your database structure, but i think that works an join query...

```
$course = $this->Course
$student = $this->Student
  if(!empty($student) && !empty($course)): $status = 3 endif;   
  if(empty($student)): $status1 = 1 else: $status = 0 endif;
  if(empty($course)): $status2 = 2 else: $status = 0 endif;
    if(empty($status)):
      $array=array($status1,status2);
    else:
      $array=array($status);
    endif;
        foreach($array as $key => $value)
        if($value == 1):throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid course')); 
        if($value == 2):throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid student'));
        if($value == 0):throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid course and student')); 
        if($value == 3):throw new NotFoundException(__('Valide course and student')); 
      endforeach;
```